# Selecting elements of sublists or reshaping a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, indexing

I have this list

```
{{{0.05792, 0.31744}, 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., {0.28832, 0.49024}, {0.17173, 0.386393}, 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., {0.17173, 0.386393}, {0.104, 0.352}, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.,
   0., {0.30752, 0.38464}, {0.322232, 0.260264}, {0.214663, 
   0.107331}}, {0., 0., 
  0., {0.322232, 0.260264}, {0.392, 0.496}, {0.277128, 
   0.415692}}, {0., 0., 
  0., {0.214663, 0.107331}, {0.277128, 0.415692}, {0.2, 0.4}}}
```

or in the matrix form:
[image]

I would like to convert this list to a list of two matrices, each of the same size as the input matrix, i.e. 6 by 6, where the non-zero entries for the first matrix are given by the first element of the lists in the input matrix and the same for the second matrix.

If it helps I can also create a matrix where the zeros are replaced by a list of two zeros to match the dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst1=#1&@@@#&/@lst
```

> {{0.05792, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.28832, 0.17173, 0., 0., 0.},

> {0., 0.17173, 0.104, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.30752, 0.322232, 0.214663},

> {0., 0., 0., 0.322232, 0.392, 0.277128}, {0., 0., 0., 0.214663, 0.277128, 0.2}}

```
lst2=#2&@@@#&/@lst
```

> {{0.31744, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.49024, 0.386393, 0., 0., 0.},

> {0., 0.386393, 0.352, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.38464, 0.260264, 0.107331},

> {0., 0., 0., 0.260264, 0.496, 0.415692}, {0., 0., 0., 0.107331, 0.415692, 0.4}}

Answer (score 9):

```
f = Thread @* Map[Thread];
```

With `lists`as your input list:

```
MatrixForm /@ f[lists]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can replace `0.` with `{0., 0.}` in `lists`

```
paddedlists = lists /. 0. -> {0., 0.};
```

and use `paddedlists` with  [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)
or with [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) to get the same result:

```
f @ lists == Flatten[paddedlists, {{3}, {2}, {1}}] == Transpose[paddedlists, {3, 2, 1}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted!